# Mysql EXISTS not recognizing Alias of previous table

Tags: mysql, subquery

What I try to achieve is the following, I have a Hierarchical table with data.
Each category may have 3 subcategories(maximum).
So I want to check if the subordinated subcategories have subcategories(descendants) and in the last AND condition if they have products.

The problem is that my ALIAS `tree1` is not recognized in the last AND condition.

```
/* SQL Error (1054): Unknown column 'tree1.Node_ID' in 'on clause' */
```

Here is my query, any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT tree1.Node_ID, tree1.Bez,
IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `301` as tree2 WHERE tree2.Node_Parent_ID <=> tree1.Node_ID LIMIT 1),1,0) as descendants
FROM `301` as tree1
        WHERE tree1.TreeTypNr = 1
        AND tree1.Node_Parent_ID <=> 100001
            AND EXISTS(
                SELECT * FROM `400`
                    INNER JOIN `302` ON `302`.Node_ID = tree1.Node_ID
                        WHERE `400`.GenArtNr = `302`.GenArtNr
                            AND `400`.VknZielNr = 18302
                            AND `400`.VknZielArt = 2
                                LIMIT 1
            )
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM `400`
                    INNER JOIN `302` ON `302`.Node_ID = tree1.Node_ID If you want to compare a value from tree1 you must move this condition in WHERE clause. In ON clause you must compare field about 400 and 302 table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've swapped two rows:

```
`400`.GenArtNr = `302`.GenArtNr (put in ON cluase)
```

and

```
`302`.Node_ID = tree1.Node_ID (put in WHERE condition)
```

Try this:

```
SELECT tree1.Node_ID, tree1.Bez,
IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `301` as tree2 WHERE tree2.Node_Parent_ID <=> 
tree1.Node_ID LIMIT 1),1,0) as descendants
FROM `301` as tree1
    WHERE tree1.TreeTypNr = 1
    AND tree1.Node_Parent_ID <=> 100001
        AND EXISTS(
            SELECT * FROM `400`
                INNER JOIN `302` ON `400`.GenArtNr = `302`.GenArtNr
                    WHERE `302`.Node_ID = tree1.Node_ID
                        AND `400`.VknZielNr = 18302
                        AND `400`.VknZielArt = 2
                            LIMIT 1
        )
```

Comment: Have a nice day ;)